# How do I use mapview in R from a server?

Tags: r, spatial, hpc

I am able to use XForwarding to see traditional plots on my home computer that I generate on a Linux server (CentOS in this case).

However, I would like to also forward plots that usually appear in the browser when run locally (`plotly`, `leaflet`, `mapview`).

Is this possible? If so, can I have some pointers to get started?

Answer (score 0):

For me it works out of the box.

Connect to server:

```
> ssh -X my-server.org
```

Start firefox and wait (a looong time on my server):

```
> firefox &
```

Start R and make a leaflet plot which will display in Firefox (after looong):

```
> R
> library(leaflet)
> m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
> m
```